# Merge Sort Three Sub-Vectors

Tags: c, vector, mergesort

I'm doing a version of merge sort that instead of dividing the vector into two sub-vectors, just by dividing the array into 3 sub-vectors only am I having a problem in this thesis the algorithm only right that the program closes, I could help please, follow the code below to review:

```
void Intercala(int v[],int inicio,int meio1,int meio2,int fim)
{
int i,j,k,*w;
w=(int*)malloc((fim-inicio)*sizeof(int));
i=inicio;
j=meio1;
l=meio2;
k=0;
while(i<meio1&&j<meio2)
{
    if(v[i]<=v[j])
        w[k++]=v[i++];
    else
        w[k++]=v[j++];
}
while(l<fim)
{
    w[k++]=v[l++];

}
while(i<meio1)
    w[k++]=v[i++];
while(j<meio2)
    w[k++]=v[j++];
while(l<fim)
    w[k++]=v[l++];
for(i=inicio;i<fim;i++)
    v[i]=w[i-inicio];
free(w);        
}
void Merge_Sort(int v[],int inicio,int fim)
{
int meio1,meio2;
if(inicio<fim-1)
{
    meio1=(inicio+fim)/3;
    meio2=meio1*2;
    Merge_Sort(v,inicio,meio1);
    Merge_Sort(v,meio1,meio2);
    Merge_Sort(v,meio2,fim);
    Intercala(v,inicio,meio1,meio2,fim);
}
}
```

Comment: meio1=(inicio+fim)/3;

This is problematic. It is not guaranteed to be between inicio and fim (I believe your intent is for it to be inicio + (fim-inicio)/3 )

Similarly, meio2=meio1*2 is problematic. It should be inicio + (fim-inicio)*2/3. Making a variable for the size would make this cleaner.

tamano = (fim-inicio);
meio1 = inicio + tamano/3;
meio2 = inicio + tamano*2/3;

Answer (score 1):

[Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is a divide and conquer algorithm. In the standard implementation, you first split the list up into two sublists, recursively sort those two lists, then merge those two sorted lists into one sorted list.

With three subvectors, it's the exact same thing, except you need to tweak your divide and merge logic to handle three vectors instead of two. At a high level, it should look something like this:

```
void merge_sort(int v[], int len)
{
    /* Code to handle the base case (lists of length 1) */
    /* ... */

    /* v1-v3, len1-len3 are out parameters */
    divide(v, v1, &len1, v2, len2, v3, len3);

    merge_sort(v1, len1);
    merge_sort(v2, len2);
    merge_sort(v3, len3);

    merge(v, len, v1, len1, v2, len2, v3, len3);
}
```

Unfortunately I don't speak the language that the code was originally written in so I'm having trouble making sense of the original intent of your code, but some questions/suggestions I have include:

- Are you correctly handling the base case?
- Why does `Intercala()` dynamically allocate additional memory? This should not be necessary in merge sort, since merge sort can work in place.
- This problem is very well suited for unit testing -- for any input, you can easily determine the output. As such, consider writing some unit tests for `Intercala()` to see whether it works in all the cases you can think of. Once you know `Intercala()` works, consider writing unit tests for the entire `Merge_Sort()` algorithm.

Good luck!

Comment: hi john you have a template function divides?

Because I think the more correct in this meumerge divides this happening something strange I thank your attention.